# EJS with template literals in form

Tags: javascript, ejs

I need insert a id with template literals in action prop, inside a form.

Example:

```html
  <div>
    <h6>Cookmaster - Receitas</h6>

    // Similar Template, but i need a EJS template

    <form action={`/recipes/${id}`} method="POST">
      <label for="title">Título da Receita</label>
      <input type="text" id="title" name="title" value=<%= title %>>
      <br>
      <label for="ingredients">Ingredientes</label>
      <textarea type="text" id="ingredients" name="ingredients" value=<%= ingredients %>></textarea> 
      <br>
      <label for="detailsRecipe">Modo de Preparo</label>
      <textarea type="text" id="detailsRecipe" name="detailsRecipe" value=<%= detailsRecipe %>></textarea>
      <br>
      <button type="submit">Enviar Receita</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

But i don't know how to insert a template literal in this situation.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Where is `id` defined?

Comment: defined at controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many attempts, there it is:

```
 <form action=<%= `/recipes/${id}` %> method="POST">
```

tks.

Comment: I found that some html attributres require outer quote wrapping in order to achieve desired result. Example: ```<button  title="<%= `Delete ${item.displayName}` %>">.....</button>```